# Jquery Mobile Automated Image Corousel

Tags: jquery-mobile

I was working with a mobile site in jQuery Mobile.

I need to use automated image Carousel for my home page. I have used `tiny carousel` but it contains static values for css parameters and, hence, does not provide good results for mobile `view.Kindly`.

Could you suggest one which can be useful?

Comment: Now i have used flexslider jquery plugin.It works well for my mobile App.Here is the link: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: Nice plugin. You can close this question if you are satisfied with above plugin.